# AngularJS txn.price is non-assignable

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS and trying to format float in input text as below.

```
<input ng-model="txn.price | number:3" name="price" ng-pattern="/^\d+([,.]\d+)?$/" md-maxlength="30" required ng-change="calcUnits()">
```

but i am getting below error.

```
Error: ngModel:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression
Expression 'txn.price' is non-assignable. Element: {1}
```

Comment: What does your data model look like?

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign.  It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is non assignable because you are running the model through a filter.  This means the data can't be set because you are modeling a return value instead of the original item.  You need to change your model to ng-model="txn.price"

Alternatively you may want to use `$filter('number')(txn.price, 3)` in your controller function.

`$filter('number')(number, fractionSize)`

Comment: Thanks I modified angularJs plucker which uses angular 1.6 and there it's working fine. for me i am using angular 1.5.
[link]https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview[/link]

Comment: Great, so this answer worked for you? (you can selected it as best answer if so)

Comment: So finally i ended up using ` $filter('number')(number, fractionSize) ` in my controller function